# Get current time in milliseconds

Tags: r

I am trying to do an API call which requires a time in milliseconds. I am pretty new in R and been Googling for hours to achieve something like what In Java would be:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Only thing i see is stuff like

`Sys.Date()` and `Sys.time`

which returns a formatted date instead of time in millis.

I hope someone can give me a oneliner which solves my problem.

Comment: **Update** I checked out the Java function and I guess you really did mean time *in* milliseconds afterall.

Comment: Do you mean **the** time in milliseconds or **a** time in milliseconds?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Sys.time` does not return a "formatted time". It returns a `POSIXct` classed object, which is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch. Of course, when you *print* that object, it returns a formatted time. But how something prints is not what it is.

To get the current time in milliseconds, you just need to convert the output of `Sys.time` to numeric, and multiply by 1000.

```
R> print(as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000, digits=15)
[1] 1476538955719.77
```

Depending on the API call you want to make, you might need to remove the fractional milliseconds.

Comment: for the lazy ones (removing the fractional ms):      current_timestamp = round(as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000)

Answer (score 6):

No need for setting the global variable `digits.secs`.
See `strptime` for details.

```
# Print milliseconds of current time
# See ?strptime for details, specifically
# the formatting option %OSn, where 0 <= n <= 6 
as.numeric(format(Sys.time(), "%OS3")) * 1000
```

Comment: It's just the millisecond component of the current timestamp. Not sure if that's what was intended. You might want to add the rest of the timestamp.

Comment: From what I understand OP wants the current system time's seconds expressed in milliseconds.

Comment: Maybe OP can clarify. Converting the rest of the timestamp into milliseconds is trivial. I will append my answer if that's the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

To get current epoch time (in second):

```
as.numeric(Sys.time())
```

If you want to get the time difference (for computing duration for example), just subtract `Sys.time()` directly and you will get nicely formatted string:

```
currentTs <- Sys.time()
# about five seconds later
elapsed <- Sys.time() - currentTs
print(elapsed)    # Time difference of 4.926194 secs
```